# "She is living out at her home" or "She is living out her life at her home" - which sentence is more grammatically correct?

Tags: pronouns, grammaticality-in-context

There are two sentences:

- She is living out at her home.
- She is living out her life at her home.

I was said that the first is wrong as It doesn't contain "her life". Is it really so much important to have this addition If my context is about dying?

Comment: It's not really a matter of grammar - and both are a bit awkward, 'at home' already conveys ownership or belonging - but there's no clear indication of what either version is really supposed to mean, except the second sounds like she's waiting to die:\  We need **context**.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. My context is just about death. Then "her life" adds meaning of dying, right?

Comment: You need to add this detail clearly to your question, not just in comments.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. Sure

Comment: You are translating literally en su casa. We just say: at home.

Comment: [correction: I was told, not I was said.] to live out one's life is an idiom.

Comment: The first one sounds as though her home is 'out' in the country, in a sparsely populated area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "live out somewhere" is a completely different verb from to "live your life out". In fact, the two can be combined into a single sentence:

> She's living her life out out at her home.

In "live out at her home", "live" is a stand-alone verb with the normal meaning, and "out at her home" is an adverbial that gives the location of living.

In "live out her life", "live out" is a phrasal verb with the object "her life". This phrasal verb means roughly to *live the full extent of* some time period, usually the person's life, but it can also be things like a prison sentence.